# One-to-one lazily load with optional=false but how to save associated subobject with null

Tags: java, hibernate, persistent

At first, let me describe the related two classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "db_consumer_master", name = "t_consumer")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class Customer{
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =   FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    public CustomerWallet getWallet() {
        return wallet;
    }
}


public class CustomerWallet {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "customer_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name = "property", value = "customer"))
    private long customerId;
    private long amount;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Customer customer;
}
```

to enable lazily load, just setting fetch = FetchType.LAZY does not work, so I add "optional = false", but now, new problem occures:

I want to create a new Lawyer object by calling session.save(lawyer). Here is the code snippet to make a lawyer instance:

```
Customer customer= new Customer();
CustomerWallet wallet = new CustomerWallet();
customer.setWallet(wallet);
```

when save(customer) is called, exception is thrown out:

**IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property**

So, my question is, how to save this customer object with wallet object being null here? wallet need a customer id as the shared primary key as the association. but we will not get this customer id until customeris persisted into database. Am i required to generate ID in java instead of database system? are there any other options for this case?

Comment: shouldn't mappedBy be `customer` ? and what is generator "gen" ? I think it should be "foreign"

Comment: you need the attribute lawyer in your CustomerWallet class

Comment: and I think `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` for field `customer` in `CustomerWallet` is wrong because it's not the primary key of the `CustomerWallet` class

Comment: "gen" is a name of the id generator. I borrowed it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> to enable lazily load, just setting fetch = FetchType.LAZY does not work, so I add "optional = false"

The `optional` attribute is not there to force lazy loading. It is defined in the JPA 2.0 specification as follows:

> (Optional) Whether the association is optional. If set to false then a non-null relationship must always exist.

And here is how lazy loading is stated in the spec:

> (Optional) Whether the association should be lazily loaded or must be eagerly fetched. The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider runtime that the associated entity must be eagerly fetched. The LAZY strategy is a hint to the persistence provider runtime.

Which means the persistence provider is not obliged to lazy load the associated entity.

Now to your question:

> So, my question is, how to save this customer object with wallet object being null here?

1. First of all define your mappings correctly
   You are using `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation on the association to `Customer`. This annotation is used to join a subclass to its parent in the **JOINED** mapping strategy. But in your case, your entities do not inheritance relationship. So you have to use **JoinColumn** annotation instead:

   ```
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = <name_of_foreign_key>) (Optional)
   private Customer customer;
   ```
2. Remove `optional = false` from the `@OneToOne` annotation in the `Customer` class.
3. Your `foreign key` column must allow `NULL` values. Otherwise, you will get referential contraint violation exception.

Comment: Many thanks to ujulu. the database schema was generated with hibernate4-maven-plugin from java classes, so the "name_of_foreign_key" my be changed everytime the schema was generated. how to deal in this case?

Comment: By the way,  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn  can be used to map a shippingAddress in the User class as a shared primary key association. excerpted from book <Java Persistence with Hibernate> Page No. 281.

Comment: In this case `JoinColumn` is optional and you can remove from the annotation (see the modified post above). What the `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` is concerned see [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single). By the way, I haven't read that book.